# Regex pattern in batch is not matching subpatterns

Tags: regex, batch-file, command-prompt, regex-group

I'm trying to match values `ABC-2131` and  `ABC-345,DEF-3534` and `EFG-456,FGF-4546,HJI-23423` against RegEx in batch script

```
^([aA-zZ]*-[0-9]*)([,]*[aA-zZ]*-[0-9]*)*
```

The Regex Sub patterns are not matched correctly in batch script

E.g. In sub pattern grouping, `^([aA-zZ]*-[0-9]*)` is valid only for `(ABC-234)` and not for `ABC-234`

Here's the code:

```
echo(%LogMsg%|findstr /r /c:"^([aA-zZ]*-[0-9]*)([,]*[aA-zZ]*-[0-9]*)*" >nul && (
echo FOUND
) || (
(echo NOT FOUND )
)
```

Comment: You can try: `^[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+(?:,[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+)*$`

Comment: No. I need to match only ABC-2131 or  ABC-345,DEF-3534

Comment: Yes, I tried. That didn't worked for ABC-342

Comment: That's not correct. See this demo: https://regex101.com/r/JhHvxR/1 It matches all of your input strings.

Comment: OK. But the problem only exist for 'Regex in batch script'

Comment: May be it doesn't support `?:`, try `^[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+(,[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+)*$`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221129/discussion-between-adrienbruce-and-anubhava).

Comment: The [`findstr` command](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) only supports a very poor set of regular expressions; there is no grouping with `(`/`)`, for instance. How many comma-separated items may occur in your text to be searched?

Comment: There can any number of ABC-3454 patterns separated by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`findstr` command](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) only supports a very tiny excerpt of regular expressions. Furthermore, the length of the search expression is very limited.

A possible way is to let a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) split the string at commas, which constitute a standard token separator in batch, then check each iterated item to comply with a certain pattern:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Assign sample string:
set "LogMsg=ABC-2131,ABC-345,DEF-3534,EFG-456,FGF-4546,HJI-23423"

rem /* Assign string to `for` meta-variable, just to protect potential
rem    special characters without using delayed variable expansion: */
for %%J in ("%LogMsg%") do (
    rem /* Loop through comma-separated items
    rem    (actually, any sequence consisting of SPACE, TAB, `,`, `;`,
    rem    `=`, VTAB, FF, NBSP is treated as a token separator): */
    for %%I in (%%~J) do (
        rem // Assign current item to variable:
        set "ITEM=%%I"
        rem // Match item against predefined pattern:
        cmd /V /C echo(!ITEM!| findstr /I "^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9]*$" || goto :SKIP
    )
)
rem // This point is reached when all items match:
echo FOUND
exit /B
rem // This point is reached when any item does not match:
:SKIP
echo NOT FOUND
```

Regard that `findstr` has got some flaws:

- an upper-case character class `[A-Z]` also matches lower-case letters (except for `z`), so I decided to do a case-insensitive search (`/I`);
- a character class like `[A-z]` may also match special letters like `Å`, `à`, etc., depending one the current code page;
- a character class like `[0-9]` may also match a few special characters like <sup>`2`</sup>, <sup>`3`</sup>, depending on the current code page;
- to prevent such issues you need to avoid character ranges and specify every possible character, like `[0123456789]`; but remember the limited length of search strings;